# How to parse more than one xml file in python code?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

Hi i want to parse 2 xml files in my python code.And want to replace tag value in strings.xml using tags value from config.xml .As i'm new to python i don't have any clue.

Here is my code:

```
**import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root= ET.parse("C:/Users/Desktop/B-C-
Final/BuildConfig/Droid/Resources/values/Strings.xml")
search = root.findall(".//string/.[@name='app_name']")
print(search[0].text)
src= ET.parse("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\B-C-Final\\BuildConfig\\BuildConfig\\Config.xml")
appname = src.findall(".//string/.[@name='app_name']")
search[0].text = search[0].text.replace('search[0].text','appname[0].text')**
```

But i'm getting error like:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/Pythoncode/hello.py", line 9, in <module>
  src= ET.parse("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\B-C-Final\\BuildConfig\\BuildConfig\\Config.xml")
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
  tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 595, in parse
  self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
  xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 11, column 16**
```

This is config file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
  <add key="K0" value="0" />
  <add key="K1" value="1" />
  <add key="K2" value="2" />
</appSettings>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />
<application android:label="Build" android:icon = "@hello/icon"> 
</application>
<string name="app_name">abc</string>
</configuration>
```

Comment: do you want to get here the values of your variables? 'search[0].text','appname[0].text'

Comment: yes i want those values to be copied in my string.xml . Eg. to get the value of app_name from config.xml and replace app_name value in string.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = utils.getFileContent("config.xml")
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
app_name = doc.select('string@name=app_name').text

html1 = utils.getFileContent("Strings.xml")
doc1 = SimplifiedDoc(html1)

app_name1 = doc1.select('string@name=app_name')
app_name1.setContent(app_name)
print (app_name1.outerHtml)

utils.saveFile("Strings.xml",doc1.html)
```

Result:

```
<string name="app_name">abc</string>
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples